# How can I say "noexcept if execution of protected base constructor is noexcept"?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, protected, noexcept

We had this situation and wondered about the best way to fix it

```
template<typename T>
struct A : T {
  A(T &&t) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::move(t))))
     :T(std::move(t))
  { }
};
```

This unfortunately fails to compile because T's move constructor is protected, and we are only allowed to call it in the constructor initialization list for `*this`. What are the workarounds to make this work or is there even a standard way for it?

Comment: “and we are only allowed to call it in the constructor initialization list for `*this`” — wait, what? Is this a special rule for protected *constructors*? That you can only use them in the initialisation list?

Comment: Which compiler fails to compile it?

Comment: @ecatmur Intel/GCC fails (Clang probably aswell). As with all protected functions, only calls through objects of the type of `*this` or derived classes are permitted.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb So what you’re stumbling over here is the lack of a dedicated syntax to call the constructor for `this`? This looks like a pretty bad oversight. Is using placement-new in `noexcept` legal (and even if it’s legal: does it propagate the `noexcept`ness of the constructor it calls)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph we ended up creating a `struct Dummy : T { Dummy(T &&t):T(std::move(t)) { } };` and doing `noexcept(Dummy(std::move(t)))` in the ctor of `A`, but it strikes me as very ugly and we wonder about a better way.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don’t understand why this works: doesn’t `Dummy`’s constructor have the same problem? Who don’t you need to declare it as `noexcept`? Does the compiler infer it here? Then why doesn’t it infer it for `A`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph ah you are right, I think we did instead use the implicitly generated move constructor of `Dummy`. Since it ended up calling `T::T(T&&)` aswell and deduces the noexceptedness automatically.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Ah, that makes sense. I think this is a sensible solution if you make `Dummy` a template and name it properly, maybe with an appropriate wrapper function, e.g. `noexcept(noexcept(has_noexcept_move_constructor<T>()))`. That should work, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think so, but perhaps there's something else? Is it a known defect that C++17 fixes with something better? `noexcept(auto)` perhaps?

Comment: Wait a second, shouldn't this just work according to [class.access]/6?

Comment: OK, it looks like the intent is to have [class.protected] apply, but the wording is not quite there yet - [CWG1883](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1883).

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value)`:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible

Comment: This does not appear to work because the move constructor is protected and the trait has no access to it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb seems you have to add is as a friend of base class.